# print a file content side by side bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a file with below contents. I need to print each line side by side

```
hello
1223
man
2332
xyz
abc
```

Output desired:

```
hello 1223
man   2332
xyz   abc
```

Is there any other alternative than paste command?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to be avoiding `paste`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{ORS = (NR%2 ? FS : RS)} 1' file

hello 1223
man 2332
xyz abc
```

This sets `ORS` (output record separator) equal to input field separator (`FS`) for odd numbered lines, for even numbered lines it will be set to input record separator (`RS`).

To get tabular data use `column -t`:

```
awk '{ORS = (NR%2 ? FS : RS)} 1' file | column -t

hello  1223
man    2332
xyz    abc
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you please tell me what is the "1" in awk ?

Comment: `1` is default action in `awk` to print each record.

Answer (score 1):

awk/gawk solution:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"} { COL1=$1; getline; COL2=$1; print(COL1,COL2)}' file
hello   1223
man     2332
xyz     abc
```

Bash solution (no paste command):

```
$ echo $(cat file) | while read col1 col2; do printf "%s\t%s\n" $col1 $col2; done
hello   1223
man     2332
xyz     abc
```